# Check if a children is element or text

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML that can look like this:

```
<div class='parent'>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices massa nec velit maximus efficitur. Fusce luctus augue elit, ac varius magna tincidunt ac.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

or

```
<div class='parent'>
  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices massa nec velit maximus efficitur. Fusce luctus augue elit, ac varius magna tincidunt ac.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </h1>
</div>
```

I want to check if the children of the div with the class 'parent' is either a text node or an element.

I tried using nodeType but for some reason it always returns 3. As if their respective children is always a text node.

```
const element = document.querySelector('.parent');
const childNode = element.childNodes[0];
if (childNode.nodeType === 3) {
  console.log('The child node is a text node.');
} else {
  console.log('The child node is not a text node.');
}
```

Comment: Try `childNode.nodeName` - in your case it gets H1 as opposed to integer values

Comment: The whitespace usually is also a child of text type, while the second child could be a element-node.

Comment: the reason why you are getting in both cases a childNode of type text as the first child it's because also in the case where there's a nested h1 child, the very first child it's a new line inside a text node. So maybe your check should go further and inspect also the `.children` property

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes: _"It is important to keep in mind that childNodes includes all child nodes, including non-element nodes like text and comment. To get a collection containing only elements, use Element.children instead."_ So you should be able to just use `if (!element.children.length)`, if you just want to determine whether an element contains _any_ children, or text only. (In the latter case, the element might still be completely empty - if you need to handle that differently, you'll still need to check that.)

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through all the children and check the nodeType. While there usually is text-nodes, also the element-nodes should be available as children.

Answer (score 1):

- a `Node` can either be a `text` node or an `element` node. An `element` node cannot be a `text` node.
- `element.children` will always return `element` nodes
- `element.childNodes` will return BOTH `element` and `text` nodes.

Both `HTMLLiveCollection` and `NodeList` have `Symbol.iterator` defined on them, so you can do something like this:

```
const el = document.querySelector('.parent'),
      sortEls = (el) => {
        children: [...el.children], 
        textNodes: [...el.childNodes].filter(d => d.nodeType === 3)
      };
sortEls(el);//...children and text nodes
```

You do not need fault checking, they will always return empty arrays, in case there are no children/nodes.